# pan gesture recongizer not working with if statement

Tags: swift, if-statement, self, uipangesturerecognizer

In my swift code below i have 2 objects with the goal of only one of them having a pan gesture applied to them at a time. Right now my code works with one of the boxes but when the if statement is applied I can control the other box by touching the first box. I can dragged and drop both boxes when the correct if statement is applied.
[image]

```
    import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var frontBox = UIButton()
    var backBox = UIButton()
    var selectorB = UIButton()

    var selctorValue = 0
    
    var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

    // constraint we will modify when slider is changed
    var backBoxWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // constraints we will modify when backBox is dragged
    var backBoxCenterY: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var backBoxLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    
    var FrontBoxWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // constraints we will modify when backBox is dragged
    var FrontBoxCenterY: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var FrontBoxLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    
    
    
    
    
    var tim = 50.0
  
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [backBox,selectorB,frontBox].forEach{
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor(
                red: .random(in: 0.0...1),
                green: .random(in: 0.9...1),
                blue: .random(in: 0.7...1),
                alpha: 1
            )
        
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
     
            
            selectorB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            selectorB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            selectorB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.1),
            selectorB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 1),
            
        ])

        // backBox Width constraint
        backBoxWidth = backBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.2)
        
        // backBox CenterY constraint
        backBoxCenterY = backBox.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        
        // backBox Leading constraint
        backBoxLeading = backBox.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: CGFloat(tim))
        
        
        // backBox Width constraint
        FrontBoxWidth = frontBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.2)
        
        // backBox CenterY constraint
        FrontBoxCenterY = frontBox.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        
        // backBox Leading constraint
        FrontBoxLeading = frontBox.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: CGFloat(tim))
        
        
        
        
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // backBox Height is constant
            backBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.5),
            
            backBoxWidth,
            backBoxLeading,
            backBoxCenterY,
            
            frontBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.3),
            
            FrontBoxWidth,
            FrontBoxCenterY,
            FrontBoxLeading,
            
        ])
        
        panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(draggedView(_:)))
        
     

        
        
        selectorB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(press), for: .touchDown)
        frontBox.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        backBox.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
       
        frontBox.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        backBox.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
 
        
    }
    

    
    @objc func draggedView(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
       
        if selctorValue == 1 {
            // update backBox Leading and CenterY constraints
            let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
            backBoxLeading.constant += translation.x
            backBoxCenterY.constant += translation.y
            sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
       
        }
        else {
         
            let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
            FrontBoxLeading.constant += translation.x
            FrontBoxCenterY.constant += translation.y
            sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
            
          
        }
        
       
        
    
        
        
        
    }
 
    @objc func press(){
        selctorValue = selctorValue == 0 ? 1 : 0
        
    }

}


 [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: What's the question? Seems like you are toggling the `selctorValue` regardless so no big surprise here?

Comment: if i press 1 the backbox should move if i press 0 only the front box should move that is not happening.

Comment: Why are you showing code for constraints?  Do you have to?

Comment: "In my swift code below i have 2 objects with the goal of only one of them having a pan gesture applied to them at a time."  That's simply a bad design.

Comment: While I'm not (yet) calling this a bad design, I need to ask - what is your objective with this? Maybe there is a better design.

Comment: @ElTomato i added a gif above

Comment: @dfd i added a gif above

Comment: @matt i added a gif above

Comment: I'd break down your code a bit. If what you claim the issue is - and I see by the GIF it probably is -  separate your constraint and slider code completely from the pan gesture code. Put them in separate function if you need to and move them to an extension.. Isolate the pan gesture code as much as possible. Next, make sure your way of separating which pan gesture is working correctly by using well-placed breakpoints. Personally, I'd do this differently - use the tag property of the view to identify which is being panned so you eliminate the troublesome if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminate the if statement and use object oriented programming. One pan gesture recognizer for different views is silly. Gesture recognizers can be enabled or disabled. So just give each view its own pan gesture recognizer and have the button toggle which one is enabled.

Comment: can you code each view having there own pan gesture i will give you the points if you do it.

Comment: My answer describes what I think you should do. I believe that following my advice will solve the problem easily. I do not propose to write your code for you.